# NoReverseMatch: error, cant use object.get_absolute_url() in template

Tags: django, templates, url

I've model Article with "slug" attribute which fills in overriden method save():

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=50000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('articles:ArticleDetailView', args=[self.slug])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and try to display it with generic view DetailView:

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
```

As I understand from documentation defoult value for "slug_field" is 'slug'. So if we try to use it with url:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_view'),
```

it works
But if I use in template method get_absolute_url():

```
 <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
```

django raises error

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'articles.views.ArticleDetailView' with arguments '('title-1',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL pattern is not called ArticleDetailView, it is called "article_view", because you've given it an explicit name. You should use that name in the reverse call.

Also, since you're using a named group when capturing the slug, you should use kwargs.

```
return reverse('articles:article_view', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify an name on the url schema use that for reversing as django ignores the rest:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article_view', {'slug': self.slug })
```